# Multiple links on one web part image

Tags: web-part, image

I have an Image Web Part, within the linked image I would like to have multiple links on it,  on specific areas.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Image Web Part doesn't allow specifying usemap attribute, so I'd recommend using Script Editor webpart instead and deal with code. It's not difficult at all.

E.g. simplest code for an image tag looks like this:

```
<img src="http://site.com/path/to/your/image.png" />
```

In your case you should also add usemap attribute:

```
<img src="http://site.com/path/to/your/image.png" usemap="#myimagemap1" />
```

Then, create a map for this image and paste it next to your image tag, e.g. like this:

```
<map id="myimagemap1" name="imgmap20149513424">
    <area shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="227,57,26" href="/Page1.aspx" target="" />
</map>
```

*Notice that id of the image map should be same as value of usemap attribute without `#`.*

To create an image map, you can use a number of applications:

Online image map editor:

- http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap

Open Source image map editor - windows application:

- http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/XMap/

Finally, there is even a JS image map editor, so that you can even embed it into your portal:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/593037/Image-Map-Editor-Fabric-vs-ImageMapster-and-Virtua

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is possible with an image web part but if you used a content editor webpart then you could create a good old fashioned image map.

http://sharepointadmin.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/cewpimagemap/

Answer (score 0):

On Modern SharePoint none of the above is possible anymore. A nifty workaround is to make use of PowerPoint and embed a slide with imagemaps